# Object Destructuring with React hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a simple code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register("firstName", { required: true })} />
      {errors.firstName?.type === 'required' && "First name is required"}
      
      <input {...register("lastName", { required: true })} />
      {errors.lastName && "Last name is required"}
      
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

form [the official](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started) React Hook Form page.

My question regards the code:

```
const { register, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();
```

from the example above. I understand that it's just the `Object Destructuring` on *hook function* assignment but how the `formState: { errors }` works there and what does it really does?

Comment: The code is destructuring `formState` and then extracting `errors` from `formState`.

Comment: @Hassan Imam Yah. I know that's  destructuring formState BUT once again what is the `formState: { errors }` inside the destructuring object ?

Comment: If you know what it is and what it does, what are you asking about then?

Answer (score 0):

Nested destructuring:

```js
function nested() {
    return {
        really: { nested: { object: 42 } },
    };
}

const { really: { nested: { object } } } = nested();

console.log(object); // 42
```

Note that you cannot use `really` or `nested` as identifiers, only `object`, because that's what's being extracted.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your userForm() function is defined as

```
function useForm() {
    return {
        formState: {
            errors: {}
        }
    }
}
```

Then you may do something like

```
let { formState: { errors}} = useForm();
```

This is equallent to

```
let useFromResponse = userForm();
let errors = useFormResponse.formState.errors;
```

You are doing a nested destructing here and yaa once done you can use `errors` but not `formState`.